# Restful web service in java

Tags: java, rest

I have a project and i was trying to create a restful webservis. I searched a lot and almost finished all the net documentation. Always having a problem. Can someone say me a good webservis sample which has got server and client side in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a good experience with [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/). It handles both the client and server side well.
The tutorials are also good enough to get you started.

Answer (score 5):

The standard API for RESTful web services which is going to be included in Java EE 6 (to be released later in 2009) is [JAX-RS](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/). [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is Sun's reference implementation of this API, which is included in Glassfish v3.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is doing something like this:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/restful/

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking into using a framework like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html), but from your question it isn't clear what kind problems you're running into.. Care to explain what you've tried already and what kind of service you're trying to build? Detailed questions get better answers..

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.0 will support REST.